# How to use .htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Okay, so I here .htaccess redirect is a pretty big deal, but I dont know how to do it. Honestly I'm a n00b, so can someone tell me how this is even accomplished? So far I know you have to have a page called

```
example.com/example.html
```

and then you want it to look like this:

```
example.com/example/
```

My problem is, how do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be achieved by adding the following to your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /$1/ [R,L]
```

The above will change any page with a `html` extension to `FILEANME/`

Comment: Ok thank you! Oh and when I upload this file to a web server, I heard there might be complications?

Comment: Possibly, but there can be complications when you do nearly anything. Anything specific you heard?

Comment: Yes someone said something about your file disappearing when you upload via FTP.

Comment: Also something about having your ftp in some kind of different saving mode... Weird stuff, but do you have any problems with your stuff???

Comment: I haven't had any problems yet.